# select a date in a period of time

Tags: powershell, date

I want to select in a file the objects which have a date recorded in the last 8 hours, but I do not get the expected result.

My result is :

```
14/10/2020 18:16    
15/09/2020 10:15
```

The expected result :

```
14/10/2020 18:16
```

My code

```
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") 
$csv = Import-csv "$DesktopPath\files.csv" -delimiter ";"
 
$start = get-date (get-date).AddHours(-8) -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00'
$end = get-date (get-date) -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00'

$csv | ?{$_.date -ge $start -and $_.date -le $end}
```

thank you in advance for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is csv stores data as strings, so you will never get the comparison you desire without converting it into a date object.

```
$csv | foreach {$_.date.GetType().fullname}

System.String
System.String
```

Second thing is avoid formatting the date because again it will be a string.

```
$start = get-date (get-date).AddHours(-8) -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00'
$start.GetType().fullname

System.String
```

Since it's a formatted date we will need to use `[datetime]::ParseExact()` to convert it.

```
$csv | foreach {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null).gettype().fullname}

System.DateTime
System.DateTime
```

Now that we have a datetime object, we can simplify your original commands and get the desired result.

```
$csv = @'
date
14/10/2020 18:16
15/09/2020 10:15
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$start = (get-date).AddHours(-8)
$end = get-date

$csv | where {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null) -ge $start -and [datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null) -le $end}

date            
----            
14/10/2020 18:16
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer gives me the result.
However, I was obliged to have the start and end times rounded off.
From your answer and your clear explanations, I managed to adapt your proposal to get the right result.
A big thank-you!

<code>
$start = ((get-date).AddHours(-8)).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00')
$end  = (get-date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00')

$csv | where {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null) -ge $start -and [datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null) -le $end}

</code>